# HSTS bypass with sslstrip+ & dns2proxy

Tags: http, ssl, https, man-in-the-middle, hsts

I am trying to understand how to bypass HSTS protection. I've read about tools by LeonardoNve ( https://github.com/LeonardoNve/sslstrip2 and https://github.com/LeonardoNve/dns2proxy ). But I quite don't get it.

- If the client is requesting for the first time the server, it will work anytime, because sslstrip will simply strip the Strict-Transport-Security: header field. So we're back in the old case with the original sslstrip.
- If not ... ? What happens ? The client know it should only interact with the server using HTTPS, so it will automatically try to connect to the server with HTTPS, no ? In that case, MitM is useless ... ><

Looking at the code, I kinda get that sslstrip2 will change the domain name of the ressources needed by the client, so the client will not have to use HSTS since these ressources are not on the same domain (is that true?). The client will send a DNS request that the dns2proxy tool will intercept and sends back the IP address for the real domain name.At the end, the client will just HTTP the ressources it should have done in a HTTPS manner.

Example : From the server response, the client will have to download mail.google.com. The attacker change that to gmail.google.com, so it's not the same (sub) domain. Then client will DNS request for this domain, the dns2proxy will answer with the real IP of mail.google.com. The client will then simply ask this ressource over HTTP.

What I don't get is before that... How the attacker can html-strip while the connection should be HTTPS from the client to server ... ?

A piece is missing ... :s

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok after watching the video, I get a better understanding of the scope of action possible by the dns2proxy tool.
From what I understood :

- Most of the users will get on a HTTPS page either by clicking a link, or by redirection. If the user directly fetch the HTTPS version, the attack fails because we are unable to decrypt the traffic without the server certificate.
- In the case of a redirection or link with sslstrip+ + dns2proxy enabled with us being in the middle of the connection .. mitm ! ==>

  - The user goes on google.com
  - the attacker intercept the traffic from the server to the client and change the link to sign in from "https://account.google.com" to "http://compte.google.com".
  - The user browser will make a DNS request to "compte.google.com".
  - the attacker intercept the request, make a real DNS request to the real name "account.google.com" and sends back the response "fake domain name + real IP" back to the user.
  - When the browser receives the DNS answer, it will search if this domain should be accessed by HTTPS. By checking a Preloaded HSTS list of domains, or by seeing the domain already visited that are in the cache or for the session, dunno. Since the domain is not real, the browser will simply make a HTTP connection the REAL address ip.
    ==> HTTP traffic at the end ;)

So the real limitations still is that the need for indirect HTTPS links for this to work. Sometime browser directly "re-type" the url entered to an HTTPS link.

Cheers !

Comment: Another serious problem would be cached 301 redirects. When user types  `target.com` the browser tries to query `http://target.com` and then is offline redirected to `https://www.target.com` thru an old cached 301 redirect (saved on the first access), and this cache does not have an expiry date. So the only possible solution would be to manually clean caches on victim's computer. Check my [Bypassing HTTP to HTTPS cached 301 redirect to use SSLstrip](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108864/bypassing-http-to-https-cached-301-redirect-to-use-sslstrip) question.